# Combine data from multiple Access tables to produce address label, preferring PO box to Physical Address

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 database that has 3 tables, each the same.

Each of these tables is for a different telemarketer to enter leads. It is necessary for there to be multiple tables as each marketer must be treated as a separate entity.

Each of these tables has the following fields relevant to the question:

POBoxNumber
POBoxSuburb
POBoxCity
POBoxPostCode

AddressBuilding
AddressStreet
AddressSuburb
AddressCity
AddressPostCode

Now what I need to do is create a query for label printing which will prefer the PO Box to the physical address, if the PO Box is empty it will use the physical.

I then need this to be displayed as

AddrLine1
AddrLine2
AddrLine3
AddrLine4
AddrLine5

ie AddrLine1 if pobox is filled will be the PO Box number, otherwise it will be the building... and so on.

I have tried Unions and Conditional selects so far but to no avail!

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT 
   t.POBoxNumber As AddrLine1,
   t.POBoxSuburb As AddrLine2,
   t.POBoxCity As AddrLine3,
   t.POBoxPostCode As AddrLine4,
   ""  As AddrLine5
FROM TheTable t 
WHERE t.POBoxNumber Is Not Null
UNION ALL
SELECT 
   AddressBuilding As AddrLine1,
   AddressStreet As AddrLine2,
   AddressSuburb As AddrLine3,
   AddressCity As AddrLine4,
   AddressPostCode As AddrLine5
FROM TheTable t 
WHERE t.POBoxNumber Is Null
```

If this is not what you want, please explain why it is not and provide some sample data. Your question is a little vague as it stands.

Comment: Yeah that's basically it. The FROM TheTable t line, TheTable should be the name of my table i take it, how would I merge the data from 3 tables together with the same fields?

Comment: You should be able to replace TheTable with a subquery that unions the three tables, or just create a union query for the three tables and use the name of that query for TheTable.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Remou! All working perfectly. Apologies for the vague question as well but I couldn't work out how to briefly explain it.